# Is it possible to make an array of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I need to make a loop in which I need to add value on the end of the vector, so everytime i need to use `(end+1)`, but i need to do it a few time and i don't want to make a lot of tables for this. In this way I need array of vectors like for example in c++. In c++ u use just `[1][2]` for example to get to this and it's fine but I don't know how to do it in MATLAB. I can't just make static matrix, beacuse my points are generating in while true loop and I draw plots in real time. I was trying something like this:

```
tab = [4, []];
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this sort of situation is difficult to deal with in Matlab.
You can have a array of verctors, since the inner verctors are from the same size, otherwise you'll get an error:

```matlab
>> a = [2];
>> b = [2,3,4]
b =
     2     3     4
>> c = [a;b]
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Now, if `a` has the same size o `b`...:

```matlab
>> a = [2,2,3];
% with ; be is put in a new row
>> c = [a;b]
c =
     2     2     3
     2     3     4
% using , or space the concatenation is horizontal
>> c = [a,b]
c =
     2     2     3     2     3     4
>> c = [a b]
c =
     2     2     3     2     3     4
```

If you want to just append values to `c`, just do:

```matlab
>> c = [c 9]
c =
     2     2     3     2     3     4     9
```

I recommend you use the `cell` structure, if possible. You need to previously define the `cell` array but it can store several vectors of different sizes:

```matlab
>> cell1 = cell(2)
cell1 =
  2×2 cell array
    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
>> cell1{1} = c
cell1 =
  2×2 cell array
    {1×7 double}    {0×0 double}
    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
>> cell1{2} = a
cell1 =
  2×2 cell array
    {1×7 double}    {0×0 double}
    {1×3 double}    {0×0 double}
>> cell1{2}
ans =
     2     2     3
```

I hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks a lot of man. It works. I searched all pages and couldn't find it explained as good as you did it <3

Comment: glad it helped. Do not forget to set as "answer" please.

Comment: Note also that you can index `cell1{1}(2)` to match the C++ indexing `[1][2]` that OP used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to cell arrays is to use structure arrays. For example, you can define

```
a = [2];
b = [2,3,4]
c = [b;b]
d = [a,b]
```

And then set up a structure like below. It negates working with curly brackets

```
myStruct = struct()
myStruct(1).myVector = a
myStruct(2).myVector = b
myStruct(1).myVector2 = c
myStruct(2).myVector2 = d
```

Then `r_b` and `r_c` below "pull out" b and c

```
r_b = myStruct(2).myVector
r_c = myStruct(1).myVector2
```

Comment: That would be `myStruct(1,2).myVector`. Not exactly neater than using curly braces.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: updated my answer to be more correct ... my original had returned a structure. thanks